# javascript setInterval not working for object

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

SO, I'm trying to create a javascript object, and use the setInterval method.

This doesn't seem to be working. If I remove the quotes, then the method runs once. Any ideas why? Also, I'm using Jquery.

```
<script>
$(function(){
   var kP = new Kompost();
   setInterval('kP.play()', kP.interval);
});

var Kompost = function()
{
   this.interval = 5000;
   var kompost = this;

   this.play = function()
   {
      alert("hello");
   }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Holy Crockford, he used eval! :O

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Call it like this:

```
$(function(){
   var kP = new Kompost();
   setInterval(kP.play, kP.interval);
});
```

The problem is that `kP` is inside that `document.ready` handler and *not* available in the global context (it's only available inside that closure).  When you pass a string to `setInterval()` or `setTimeout()` it's executed in a global context.

If you check your console, you'll see it erroring, saying `kP` is undefined, which in that context, is correct.  Overall it should look like this:

```
var Kompost = function()
{
   this.interval = 5000;
   var kompost = this;
   this.play = function() {
     alert("hello");
   };
};

$(function(){
   var kP = new Kompost();
   setInterval(kP.play, kP.interval);
});
```

[You can see it working here](http://jsfiddle.net/fDcwr/)

Answer (score 8):

The solution provided by @Yacoby and @Nick, will work only if the `play` method doesn't use the `this` value inside itself, because the `this` value will point to the global object.

To handle this you need another approach, for example:

```
$(function(){
 var kP = new Kompost();
 setInterval(function () {
   kP.play();
 }, kP.interval);
});
```

See also:

- [The `this` problem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout#The_'this'_problem)

Comment: I see, thanks man. I gave the solution to Nick only because that worked very well for me. But I understand your point, and I definitely think that its a generally superior approach. Plus I didn't realize that set interval could take a function like that. +1

Answer (score 0):

It works on every where like thymeleaf etc...

```
function load() {
  alert("Hello World!");
}
setInterval(function () {load();}, 10000);
```