# javascript: the "this" issue in setInterval (again)

Tags: javascript, this, setinterval

EDIT: The practice below is NOT correct. The solution is to store "this" in another variable and use that in the setInterval function. See answers below.

```
this.growImage = function() {
        console.log("growImage:" + this.dom.id + "counter:" + this.grow_counter);
        if(this.grow_counter == 0) {
            this.tim_grow = window.setInterval(
                /******* FUNCTION TO BE CALLED BY SETINTERVAL ********/
                function() {
                    this.grow_counter++;
                    console.log("this.growStepByStep(): this.grow_counter = " + this.grow_counter); /*this is displayed as NaN */
                    if(this.grow_counter > this.times) {
                        window.clearInterval(this.tim_grow);
                        this.grow_counter = 0;
                    }
                }
                /******* FUNCTION TO BE CALLED BY SETINTERVAL ********/
            , 
            20);
        }
    }
```

EDIT: The above solution is NOT correct. 
It does not work. The console log does not "see" this.grow_counter, and displays a NaN instead. this.grow_counter is just a numeric value.

NOTE: that this function uses this inside it, so other simpler solutions won't do either. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do `var me = this` at the start of your function, and use `me` from then on.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Oh boy, you have no idea how much pain I felt before I figured that out.

Comment: Using a function expression instead of a variable referring to the function does change *nothing*. Where did you find that "*trick*"???

Comment: Bergi, I found that "trick" here:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242308/javascript-setinterval-not-working-for-object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value of `this` is NOT preserved in your `setInterval()` callback.  You have to save that value you want to another variable before the `setInterval()` call and use that inside the `setInterval()`.

```
this.growImage = function() {
    console.log("growImage:" + this.dom.id + "counter:" + this.grow_counter);
    if(this.grow_counter == 0) {
        var self = this;
        this.tim_grow = window.setInterval(
            /******* FUNCTION TO BE CALLED BY SETINTERVAL ********/
            function() {
                self.grow_counter++;
                console.log("self.growStepByStep(): self.grow_counter = " + this.grow_counter); /*this is displayed as NaN */
                if(self.grow_counter > this.times) {
                    window.clearInterval(self.tim_grow);
                    self.grow_counter = 0;
                }
            }
            /******* FUNCTION TO BE CALLED BY SETINTERVAL ********/
        , 
        20);
    }
}
```

Or, if you are using modern browsers only, you can also use `.bind()` to manipulate the value of `this` to be set as you want like this:

```
this.growImage = function() {
    function intervalCallback() {
         this.grow_counter++;
         console.log("this.growStepByStep(): this.grow_counter = " + this.grow_counter); /*this is displayed as NaN */
         if(this.grow_counter > this.times) {
            window.clearInterval(this.tim_grow);
            this.grow_counter = 0;
        }
    }

    console.log("growImage:" + this.dom.id + "counter:" + this.grow_counter);
    if(this.grow_counter == 0) {
        this.tim_grow = window.setInterval(intervalCallback.bind(this), 20);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning `.bind`, although you may want to expand on it a little bit.

Comment: @giorgian - I was working on expanding on `.bind()` - it is included now.

Answer (score 0):

Neit is correct, but to give a little bit more info.

You aren't understanding the scope that you are in when inside the setInterval.

Inside of your setInterval, you've created a new scope and 'this' only refers to things inside that new scope.  His/her suggestion of setting a variable me = this and then using me.grow_counter means you are storing the outer scope in the variable 'me', which can then be used in your setInterval scope (although I would like to see a better variable name!).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks to all for your help! Sean, I used "that" as a variable name. You know, "this" and "that" he he. It works and does not confuse me.